# Change color of specific part of DataGridView or entire column in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, styling

Is it possible to change the color of this part of a `DataGridView` by code?

[image]

If not, how can I change the color of the whole `DataGridViewRow`? I tried this code, but it does not change the color:

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
```

As information, my columns are `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`

Comment: You mean this silver color? It's possible, first set EnableHeaderVisualStyles to false then inside RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle you'll have BackColor.

Comment: erem, thanks for this. If you add this as answer, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the row colour by setting DefaultCellStyle property. In the following example we are iterating through each row and checking cell[0] value and if the condition is true then setting the row backcolor and forecolor

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in mydataGridView.Rows)
{
    string RowType = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    if (RowType == "Some Value")
    {
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**if you means to say changing the blue background** ,Blue background is the default color for a selected row in gridview. You can change this color within the properties window

```
 Gridview1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red; or Color.Transparent
 Gridview1.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black; or Color.Transparent
```

but if you are refreshing grid view in very short duration say less than 1 sec duration in that case you have to change the default color of added rows cells in Gridview,(above senario will work fine for static grid view).

```
Gridview1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;  or Color.Transparent 
Gridview1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = Color.Black;or Color.Transparent
```